# Segmentation Fault 11 after Main returns

Tags: c++

I have a pretty long program with multiple classes so I wont post it unless you need it. But after main returns I get a segmentation fault.

Using GDB I can see this error:

```
program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000002300103be8
0x00000001000035cc in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::string, std::_Identity, std::less,     std::allocator >::_S_right (__x=0x2300103bd0) at stl_tree.h:512
512       { return static_cast<_Link_type>(__x->_M_right); }
```

I'm very new to C++ so this just looks like gibberish to me. Can anyone decipher it? It looks like one of my STL containers might be causing the issue? Any advice on how to fix it?

**EDIT With Code:**

Okay so I've isolated it down to somewhere in this if block of `main`, It was the last thing I wrote and when I comment it out the program runs fine.

```
else if(line.substr(0, 3) == "Rec") // Recieve 
  {       
      istringstream ss(line);
      string s; // output string
      string upc;
      string name;
      int amount;
      int count = 0;
      while(ss >> s) // go through the words in the line
      {
          count++;
          if(count == 2)
            upc = s;
          else if (count == 3)
          {
            istringstream isa(line.substr(20, 2));
            isa >> amount; //Parse the amount
          }
          else if (count == 4)
            name = s;
      }


      warehouses.find(name)->second.receive_food(upc, amount); //add the food to the warehouse

  }
```

To clarify the `line` we are looking at is in this format:

```
Receive: 0984523912 7 Tacoma
```

`warehouses` is a map : `map<string, a4::warehouse> warehouses; //all the warehouses.`

**Here is the warehouse receive method**

```
void warehouse::receive_food(std::string upc, int amount)
{
    items.find(upc)->second.receive(amount);

    todays_transactions = todays_transactions + amount;
}
```

Where `items` is `std::map<std::string, food> items;`

**And Finally the Food Receive method**

```
void food::receive(int amount)
{
    crates.push_back(crate(life, amount));
}
```

Where `crates` is `std::list<crate> crates;`

And a `crate` is

```
    class crate
{
    public:
        crate(int, int);
        ~crate();
        int life;
        int quantity;
};
```

Comment: Need to see code.

Comment: First guess: You work with raw pointers a lot, it goes wrong somewhere and now some function deep in the STL segfaults because of that. Good luck, these kinds of things are *hard* to debug. If it's feasible, compile your program with debug symbols and test it with `valgrind`.

Comment: Before you post your code, reduce it. Shrink it to the smallest possible program that exhibits the error. Then post *that* program in your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information on that debugging technique.

Comment: @sethcarnegie updated with the code.

Comment: You use `find` without checking the returned iterator. Are you sure that it always succeeds?

Comment: @vitaut it should because the contract states that we wont "receive" a shipment to a warehouse that hasn't already been added to our warehouse map.

Comment: @Deekor: Well maybe it should, but if it hasn't for some reason you'd better give an error rather than corrupt memory.

Comment: @Deekor The same holds for `items.find(upc)->...` in `receive_food`. You need to check whether this succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a memory corruption. `_Rb_tree` suggests that the error has something to do with `std::map` which is usually implemented as a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). It is hard to say more without seeing code. I recommend using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug the issue.

After looking at the code that you've posted in the update, I think that the problem is that you don't check whether `warehouses.find(name)` returns a valid iterator. It can return `map::end()` if the key is not found.

Add a check:

```
  map<string, a4::warehouse>::iterator it = warehouses.find(name);
  if (it != warehouses.end())
    it->second.receive_food(upc, amount);
  else ; // handle the case of a missing key
```

and similar checks for other calls to `map::find`.

Comment: Which map? Or both of them? How do I go about checking it? Thanks

Comment: @Deekor: I don't know your code to say which map. Normally you should check if `find` returns `end` every time unless you are absolutely sure that the key is there.

Comment: Turns out our warehouse names were being inserted into the map with a leading space causing our find to fail.